# Normalization on different sample size

Tags: probability

I have set of sample which are grouped in different size. If I want to find probability of an event in each group, how can I normalize the probability over all the groups. For example, Let say I have 3 set of samples each sized 3, 8 and 30 respectively. If the probability of an event to occur in set $1$ is $\frac{1}{3}$, in set $2$ it is $\frac{3}{8}$ and in set $3$ it is $\frac{4}{30}$. How can I normalize the probability so that highest probability is assigned for set $3$ then set $2$ and then set $1$.

Comment: Not following.  What is this "normalized" probability meant to represent?

Comment: Use weights proportional to the size of the sample. In this case 3/41, 8/41, 30/41 (as 3+8+30=41).

Comment: Sorry if the question is not clear enough. I meant, each set has an event to occur with some probability. But if some set has 2 sample and one of them is the event then the probability is 0.5. On the other hand if a set has 10 samples and that event occurred 3 times then the probability is 3/10. But for my method second case needs to be assigned higher probability. How can I do that?

Comment: Still not following.  Are you trying to say something like "I believe the probability should be constant in each set but I don't know what the probability is.  I don't want to take a straight average because I have greater confidence in the larger sets, therefore I want to weight the observations to take the different sizes into account."  If that is what you meant, then the suggestion of @A.S. seems sensible.

Comment: I believe I need a normalizing constant that will be multiplied with each set's probability.

Comment: Ok, well if you are just trying to get a weighted average then I'd follow the earlier suggestion.  It just seems odd to me.  The third sample is so far off from the others...if it were accurate, so the per object probability was $\frac {4}{30}=.1333...$ then the probability of seeing the event $3$ times in $8$ observations, as in your second sample, is less than $6.5\%$.  Not impossible, but it seems odd.

Comment: Got it. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: @lulu $p=\frac 8 {41}$ over three sets combined which makes none of the sets as unlikely as you computed.